# Can I use Wireguard on a lowlatency kernel?

Tags: networking, kernel, vpn, wireguard

I've installed WireGuard.

```
add-apt-repository ppa:wireguard/wireguard
apt-get update
apt-get install wireguard
```

WireGuard doesn't start, because I use a lowlatency kernel. I guess that one is not supported in the `ppa`.

Kernel version:

```
4.15.0-47-lowlatency #50-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Mar 13 12:45:27 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And there is no output from the following command:

```
sudo lsmod | grep wireguard
```

How do I enable WireGuard for a lowlatency kernel?

Comment: I think I this case you have to re-compile all of Wireguard for low latency. let's see if it's open source...

Comment: oh not only is it open source but you can bake it into your kernel and compile your own kernel https://www.wireguard.com/install/#kernel-requirements is that an acceptable solution?

Comment: Sure building is an option, but that won't give you and me updates. 
Would be nice if the ppa could be updated to include an lowlatency version. that would help all `lowlatency` Linux people wanting to try out WireGuard. Which is a great VPN BTW.  
The option to use a generic module in a lowlatency kernel is fantasy, I suppose, 
For now I boot with a generic kernel to use WireGuard and boot  the lowlatency kernel when needed for audio.

Comment: I guess it's bug-reporting time then. :/